# Share 9V between relay and Arduino

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm currently trying to power both a motor connected through a relay. And an Arduino.

I just connect the power with the Arduino Vin, and create a circuit through the relay with the motor.

This works, but only when the motor is not running. When the motor starts, the Arduino restarts. I suspect this is because the motor is taking all the available current.

I'm probably missing some piece between the Arduino and the power source. Is what I'm trying to do possible? And what am I missing?

Comment: Ensure Arduino ground is low impedance to Source with no motor current flowing thru Arduino ground, then use twisted pair for all long wires. Then use Ferrite CM choke for motor noise to reduce CM noise and all interface data power lines to Arduino ( ribbon ferrite clamp around or similiar)  Then use RF cap feedthru's for data lines. This forms a high CM impedance series to low impedance shunt for CM noise which is high EH field rate of change.  then if noise is still getting in, add shields to all data IO cables with ferrite beads on board.  i.e. FET power/ground twisted pair to source.

Comment: Lastly ensure you have a low impedance Ground to absorb stray EH field noise and divert from signals , not floating unless all the above is done.

Comment: "what am I missing?" a schematic showing the power source and a link to the motor.

Comment: 9V battery by any chance? If so, no way you will run a motor from that, the internal resistance of the battery is too high.

Answer (score -1):

You may be getting a severe EMF pulse from the motor inrush current that causes the Arduino to reset. Do you have a back EMF diode close to the motor supply line?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Do you understand that inrush current and the inductive kick that you get when the current is stopped are two completely unrelated phenomena?